# Getting "Error: Invalid Usage Plan ID specified" when trying to assign API KEY to Usage Plan

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am using the nodejs aws-sdk to create an API KEY and then assign it to an usage plan created in the AWS Console

```
export async function createApiKey() {
  try {
    const secretKey = crypto.randomUUID();
    const params = {
      description: 'Secret key generate in AWS Apigateway',
      enabled: true,
      name: 'secret_key',
      value: secretKey,
    };
    const Client = new AWS.APIGatewayClient({
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
      },
    });
    const createApiKeyCmd = new AWS.CreateApiKeyCommand(params);

    const data = await Client.send(createApiKeyCmd);

    const assignApiKeyCmd = new AWS.CreateUsagePlanKeyCommand({
      keyId: data.id!,
      keyType: 'API_KEY',
      usagePlanId: process.env.AWS_USAGE_PLAN_ID!,
    });

    await Client.send(assignApiKeyCmd);

    return {
      idApiKey: data.id!,
      secretKey: data.value!,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}
```

When I run this function I get the following error: "Invalid Usage Plan ID specified". The problem is that the planId I have passed, exists at my AWS account

I have tried to use other usage plans, and also tried to specify the stageKeys, but without success

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I managed to solve it. For me the problem was in my aws config for my API GatewayClient.

When you create the api-key, double check if you can see it in AWS console.
Otherwise your config could be wrong. The sdk might've made the new API-key for another profile and not give an error there.

For the rest I seemed to have used very similar code as you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, to solve this I had to use the exact same AWS user that created the usage plan, to create the API key

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not specifying the stage key in the CreateApiKeyCommand
params. (notice the stageKeys array in the CreateApiKeyCommand params. You can see the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/api-gateway/command/CreateApiKeyCommand/).

```
export async function createApiKey() {
  try {
    const secretKey = crypto.randomUUID();
    const params = {
      description: 'Secret key generate in AWS Apigateway',
      enabled: true,
      name: 'secret_key',
      value: secretKey,
      stageKeys: [
          {
            restApiId: process.env.API_GATEWAY_ID,
            stageName: process.env.API_GATEWAY_STAGE_KEY,
          },
        ],
    };
    const Client = new AWS.APIGatewayClient({
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
      },
    });
    const createApiKeyCmd = new AWS.CreateApiKeyCommand(params);

    const data = await Client.send(createApiKeyCmd);

    const assignApiKeyCmd = new AWS.CreateUsagePlanKeyCommand({
      keyId: data.id!,
      keyType: 'API_KEY',
      usagePlanId: process.env.AWS_USAGE_PLAN_ID!,
    });

    await Client.send(assignApiKeyCmd);

    return {
      idApiKey: data.id!,
      secretKey: data.value!,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}
```